# Problem with a query: duplicate value different forms (SQL) using Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-3.6, tornado

I have a problem in my database because every day it does a new data load and ends up registering cities written in different ways, for example: "San Francisco" and "SAN FRANCISCO" which reflects in errors in the hour to show this data for the user to choose. Currently the query and the code that return this data are:

```
import tornado.web
import simplejson
import json


from tornado import gen


class LocaisHelperHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        query = """SELECT DISTINCT txt_city AS value, txt_state AS complement, 'city' AS type
                    FROM imoveis.imoveis
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT txt_neighborhood AS value, CONCAT(txt_city,', ',txt_state AS complement,
                    'txt_neighborhood' AS type
                    FROM imoveis.imoveis WHERE txt_cidade """

        cursor = yield self.application.db.execute(query)
        locals = cursor.fetchall()

        response = simplejson.dumps(locals)
        self.set_header("Content-Type", 'application/json; charset="utf-8"')
        self.set_status(200)
        self.write(response)
        return
```

My question is how to unify this query so that it shows only "San Francisco" remembering that I do not show only the city, in this query I also get data like state and neighborhood.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `upper` or `lower` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(txt_city)
```

Comment: The problem is that as I do this select it shows in the front end, if I give an upper or lower it will impact the way it is shown but thanks for participating